# Configure a dbContext from a webjob

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, dbcontext, webjob

I have a website that takes input from emails that go out to users (an email is sent to everyone, they click a link which calls a controller action). I want to use a webjob to send the emails out, but I need to cycle through all the users in the database to grab the email addresses.

I set up the website and everything is working great. I have the DbContext inheriting from IdentityDbContext here:

```
public class MooodDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public MooodDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Response> Response { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Cow> Cow { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Herd> Herd { get; set; }
    }
```

The ConfigureServices is run when I launch the webapp

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddDbContext<MooodDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MooodConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MooodDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(typeof(UnauthorizedExceptionFilterAttribute)));

            services.AddScoped<IDbInitializer, DbInitializer>();

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
            services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();

        }
```

but obviously not when I run the webjob. So, when I try to access anything in the context, I get this exception (after setting context = new context()):

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
```

It seems to me, it's because I'm not doing any configuration on the DbContext, but I'm not sure. Is there a better way to accomplish this? Or am I missing something small?

Edit: This is the program.cs of my webjob (minus the emailing functionality, which is cluttery):

```
private static MooodDbContext _context;

        // Please set the following connection strings in app.config for this WebJob to run:
        // AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage

        private static void Main()
        {
            _context = new MooodDbContext(new DbContextOptions<MooodDbContext>());

            var host = new JobHost();

            EmailAllHerds();

            host.RunAndBlock();

            EmailAllHerds();
        }
```

Comment: Could you also share how the webjob gets executed?
On another note, you could [make your life easier by using SendGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email)

Comment: Is this a console App built on `asp.net core`?, if yes then i can post code that might help

Comment: Actually, I am using SendGrid! I just didn't show the bit about sending the email to avoid clutter. Other than that, I added the program.cs parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of assumptions that i made here

- *web job is a console App built on .net core*

So you will have `Program.cs` file with a main method. So in your

**Program.cs**

```
class Program {
   // declare a field to store config values
   private readonly IConfigurationRoot _configuration;
   // Declare a constructor 
   public Program()
   {
       var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(environment.BasePath)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        _configuration = builder.Build();
   }
 }
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     var program = new Program();
     var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
     program.ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);           

  }

    private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       // now here you can resolve your DbContext similar to web
      services.AddDbContext<MooodDbContext>(options =>options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MooodConnection")));
    }
}
```

Comment: My Program.cs file doesn't have a constructor (I just added it as an edit), so that might be what I'm missing? I'm not sure what all the configurations you have are, but none of them seem related to the database. Let me try adding the Service collection bit in my main and see if that works.

Comment: you got to create one, that is the whole point of that code ^^, you are missing the DI resolution on `Program.cs` you cannot expect your `Startup.cs` on web to be called on your webjob. So you got to have the code that resolves in your console App as it is an individual dll and not connected with web

Comment: I see your point now that I've looked at it a little closer. Once question though - if you don't mind - it doesn't look like ConfigurationBuilder has any of the methods you've written? Is this not the class you're using? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder

Comment: the doc that you have is the `IConfigurationBuilder`  type - the ones that has `AddJson` etc are part of the extension namesepace  `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`. Here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.jsonconfigurationextensions

Comment: I added that because under the assumption that your console app might have its own `appSettings.json` not the one in web

Comment: Okay, I'm closer than I was before. Trying to deal with all the different nuget packages that are apparently required in Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.SoAndSo. I didn't have an appsettings.json, so I created one with just a connectionstring, hopefully that will work.

Comment: Nice! edited the code - had a typo - so you may want to  have a look at it again. had called `services` as `serviceCollection` in one of the lines above

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. Yes - I got it to work. The one thing I needed to do differently was use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() where you've got environment.BasePath (but I'm guessing that was just a placeholder you used?)